# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when loading node module during jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I am running a jest test which depends on the "antd" node module

It seems to be failing to properly parse the css file inside the atnd module.
How can I solve this?

When I run it it fails as follows:

```
C:\path\to\project\node_modules\antd\lib\style\index.css:10
html {
     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\transform.js:316:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\antd\lib\switch\style\css.js:3:1)
```

My babelrc is as follows:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015-loose",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-root-slash-import",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-runtime",
    ["import", [{"libraryName": "antd", "style" : true}]]
  ],
  "compact": true,
  "ignore": [
    "/node_modules/(?!react-number-input)"
  ]
}
```

jest.json

```
{
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jasmine-setup-env.js",
  "bail": false,
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/src/**/*.js",
    "!**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules"
  ],
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 20,
      "functions": 15,
      "lines": 20,
      "statements": 20
    }
  },
  "globals": {
    "SOURCEMAP": true
  },
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>/src",
    "<rootDir>/sass",
    "<rootDir>/public",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules",
    "<rootDir>/config"
  ],
  "resetModules": true,
  "testPathDirs": [
    "<rootDir>/test/util"
  ],
  "testRegex": "(/test/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(js|jsx)$",
  "verbose": false,
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
  ]
}
```

the js file jasmine-setup-env only adds the jasmine reporters and switches on jest-enzyme

my webpack confguration contains the following:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/main'
    ],
    output: {
        path: './public',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        // in loaders you set the plugins to use when loading specific fle extensions
        loaders: [
            {
                // any js files should be loaded by babel
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
                    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
                },
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
            },
            {
                // json files use the json loader
                test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                // any static files are loaded directly as a file
                test: /\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|woff|ttf|eot|webp)$/,
                loaders: ["file?context=public&name=/[path][name].[ext]"],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                // css fles are loaded using the css loader
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css!'
            }
        ]
    },
    // in here we specify the configuration for when we require or import specific modules
    resolve: {
        // we accept any file that is either as-is, using a .js or .json extension
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'],
        // these directories are the roots in which we scan for files given
        modulesDirectories: [
            "src",
            "sass",
            "public",
            "node_modules",
            "config"
        ],
        // these shims are needed for bunyan
        alias: {
            'dtrace-provider': path.resolve('empty-shim.js'),
            'safe-json-stringify': path.resolve('empty-shim.js'),
            "mv": path.resolve('empty-shim.js'),
            'source-map-support': path.resolve('empty-shim.js')
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        // in the provide plugin we specify which classes will be automatically replaced with requires by webpack
        // eg: Any reference to React will be replaced with require('react') without any imports required
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'React': 'react',
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery' : 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    node: {
        fs: 'empty' // we are mocking node's fs module to be empty
    }
};
```

Comment: looks like its loading your css as javascript!

Comment: the test cases should be correct in the webpack configuration however

Answer (score 0):

In my case mocking out the css content was enough

I used identity-obj-proxy as here:  https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack

Example package.json :

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
}
```

(Edited as link died)

Comment: It would be fantastic if you could include some more details. How did you mock it out? Code example? Also, the link is dead

Comment: link is now broken as well. Best guess is that [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack) is the correct link

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this on line 227 of index.js in jest-cli in the try/catch block or something similar, check your node.js version. Mine was very old (8.17.0) which produced this error & using a newer version of node fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue just now by forcing CI/CD to use a newer version of node. In my case I'm using DevOps pipeline to build and deploy the code, so just used this config bellow and everything works fine now.

```
steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '16.x'
      checkLatest: true
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```